# JQuery click event not passing variable to a post request

Tags: jquery, post, click

I am a "first-timer" and "self-taught" but have found stackoverflow invaluable in researching innumerable other questions, however I am stymied on this one. I am sure the solution is simple and can be handled in a number of ways. Apologies if I did not format or pose the question properly.

HTML

```
    <div id="message">
    <a id="date"  href="ajax1.php?postreply=1368479602">Topic</a>
    </div>
```

JQuery

```
ahref="";
timestamp="";
time="";

$(document).ready(function(){

$('a').click(function(){
    ahref = $(this).attr('href');
    timestamp = ahref.split('=');
    time = timestamp[1];

    alert(time); //this works       
})

alert(time) //this does not work

$.post('ajaxpost.php', {'timestamp' : time} , function(result) {;
    alert(result);
    })
})


</script>
```

I am able to parse href into an array and and set the second value in the array to the time variable, however I can't pass that variable to the post request. The post request works but only when I set the variable outside of the click event. I researched other posts here, and I thought the answer would be the use of global variables, even though I now understand that is not good practice, but that does not seem to be the solution although maybe I am not declaring the variables correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to prevent the default functionality of the anchor tag if you bind it with click function and make correct your json data object. json key is not quoted in single or double quotes.

the exact solution is

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
   var ahref = $(this).attr('href');
   var  timestamp = ahref.split('=');
   var time = timestamp[1];

    alert(time); //this works       
    $.post('ajaxpost.php', {timestamp : time}
           , function(result) {
         alert(result);
    });
});

});
```

Comment: There you go - thought i did it.

Answer (score 1):

Move the Ajax request to inside the click event..

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('a').click(function () {
        ahref = $(this).attr('href');
        timestamp = ahref.split('=');
        time = timestamp[1];
        $.post('ajaxpost.php', {
            'timestamp': time
        }, function (result) {;
            alert(result);
        })
    })
    alert(time); //this works       
})
```

The alert which does not work runs, when the page loads for the first time when it is empty. But you are assigning the value to it when you click event is fired.

So you need to move the Request to inside the Click event so that the correct value of time is passed to the request.

Answer (score 1):

Why would it work? The click event handler sets `time` only when it's called. It won't be called right after you bind it.

Put the code that depends on that variable in the callback:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').click(function() {
        var timestamp = this.href.split('=');
        var time = timestamp[1];

        $.post('ajaxpost.php', {
            'timestamp': time
        }, function(result) {
            alert(result);
        });
    });
});
```

Also, be careful with omitting `var`. JavaScript variables declared without `var` are automatically bound to the global scope, which rarely is what you want and may cause problems.